# How to make custom Select Boxes in HTML using CSS and JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was searching for custom Select Boxes and stumbled across [this](http://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/) URL.

I was trying to understand how the boxes work and following is what I got from it:

1. The box has a container which holds two things - the actual HTML `select` element with options and another `div` which is a sibling to the `select` which holds a list of the same items.
2. I'm assuming the list is created through JavaScript so as to prevent the user from typing the options again in HTML.
3. The `display` of the `select` is set to `none` so that it doesn't show up. The reason is that the `select` is just to submit the data when the form gets submitted but will not be shown on the page. Instead, the other `div` with the list is shown and will act as the interaction element.

Now I know how to make the other `div` look like a select element through CSS. What I'm not getting is how to "link" between the other `div` with the actual `select` element. Like, how to select the option from the `select` element when I click on one of the list item and also how to display that item on the front? Basically, how to make the other `div` act like a `select` element?

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#myselect").change(function(){
alert($( "#myselect option:selected" ).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
      <option value="1">Mr</option>
      <option value="2">Mrs</option>
      <option value="3">Ms</option>
      <option value="4">Dr</option>
      <option value="5">Prof</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: The OP clearly says it's not about selecting an option but how to style it