# Display a "traditional" html Select list on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, html-select

How can I display a "traditional" html `<select>` list on iOS rather than the iOS "picker"?

**Details:**

I have a HTML page that that displays a `<select>` list that has ~500 items in a column. The list is always displayed. Depending on the height of the browser window, the list typically displays 20-30 items.

When displayed on iOS devices, the list shows an arrow which, when tapped, pops up a small list that displays four list items. I want a "traditional" HTML list displayed (similar to the appearance in a desktop browser).

FWIW, the contents of this page (a Google Earth-like map) aren't appropriate for small devices (e.g., phones), but are very appropriate for larger screens like iPads. I limit access to the page accordingly. Also because somebody is going to say the list is too long, there are filter and search controls the user can use to limit the number of items displayed in the list. The pages uses HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and jQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, unfortunately, you can't. The behaviour of a `<select>` element is determined by the [OS/Browser](https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/) in which it is being viewed. Limited options do exist for customizing the appearance, but being able to choose between a dropdown and a picker is not one of them.

You do, however, still have a couple of options;

1. Create a completely [custom select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967535/how-to-make-custom-select-boxes-in-html-using-css-and-javascript-jquery) Note: **This is probably the route I'd take**
2. Follow IOS design patterns and emulate a [drilldown list or action sheet](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/61345/is-there-a-design-pattern-for-dropdown-lists-in-ios).

Comment: Thanks, Lewis. I have seen several roll-your-own posts for custom dropdowns (my list isn't a dropdown). I'd be okay with custom js code, but I'd prefer a well tested addin rather than having to roll-my-own.

Comment: Ah Fair enough. There's the obvious ones like jqueryUI etc, but none that I can think of that aren't dropdown based.